# Datatable Action Custom Delete Confirmation not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, datatables

Actually am trying to implement custom actions buttons (In my case using a tag) in my datatable. here i want when user click on delete link then i want a confirm box saying "Are you sure" or something like that.

```
 public function dataTable($query)
    {
        $editUrl = route('signup.index');
        // <a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" href="'.$editUrl.'/{{$id}}/delete">Delete1</a>
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Super Admin'))
            return datatables()
                ->eloquent($query)
                ->addColumn('action', '<a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" href="'.$editUrl.'/{{$id}}/delete"  onclick="return confirm(1)">Delete</a>');
        else
            return datatables()
                ->eloquent($query);
        
    }
```

Now Here when i click on delete link then it is working fine But when i pass any string in confirm function then the confimation not working.

```
 public function dataTable($query)
    {
        $editUrl = route('signup.index');
        // <a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" href="'.$editUrl.'/{{$id}}/delete">Delete1</a>
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Super Admin'))
            return datatables()
                ->eloquent($query)
                ->addColumn('action', '<a class="btn btn-info waves-effect" href="'.$editUrl.'/{{$id}}/delete"  onclick="return confirm("Are you Sure")">Delete</a>') //This is not working; 
        else
            return datatables()
                ->eloquent($query);
        
    }
```

is there any other approach for this, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a double quote `"` issue at `onclick="return confirm("Are you Sure")"`. Just using another type of quote for the string then it will work as expected. Something like:

```
onclick="return confirm(`Are you Sure`)"
```